# What is the additional benefit of Feature Flags

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am looking forward to use feature flag in my project and to inject that in my CI/CD pipeline through VSTS. Now I am unable to get the real cool use feature flags.
The control to show/hide feature can also be handled with the simple use of app settings in **web.config** and checking this in code.

```
<add key="IsFeatureAvailable" value="true" />
```

and can check this in code as :

```html
if(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IsFeatureAvailable"])
{
   //TODO Feature enhancement
}
```

In case of feature flags also the same thing I guess. A a web config settings

```
<add key="FeatureToggle.GeoLocationToggle" value="false" />
```

and check this in code as below

```html
if(Toggle.FeatureEnabled)
{
   //TODO Feature enhancement
}
```

So why should anyone use Feature flags. There must be some good positives which I am missing here. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I am not clear about your question. The key and value in web.config can be used in the code and base on the value to do something. How do you want to do it in VSTS? Do you mean ignore some tasks if the value is false?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have re-framed my question now. Hope this helps.

Comment: How it is related to VSTS or VSTS build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same, the workflow may different, for FeatureToggle.GeoLocationToggle key in web.config, you also need to get the value by using `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings`, but adding additional code to map it to a static property (FeatureEnabled) of a class (Toggle), then you can check the value of Toggle.FeatureEnabled.